# Lua registry for environment(s)?

Tags: windows, lua, registry

I'm trying to read the windows registry to figure out what scripting environments are installed and where the stand alone interpreter executables are available.

When I did python, for example, I searched for

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Python/PythonCore/InstallPath

This gives me the install path for the python executable for the environment, this allows me to find if I have python 2.7, 3, etc and where those exes are.

I'm looking for something similar for Lua for windows.

I **must** use the registry for this search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not have an install path. Lua does not have an *installation*. Lua is not like Python, with an installer that puts everything in one specific place and sets up registry and `PATH` entries and such.

The standalone interpreter does not have a mechanism to query its location. If you're interested in learning the Lua version, you can always check the `_VERSION` variable field. But other than that, no, there is no mechanism for doing what you want.

Comment: I'm not trying to use lua to find this information out, I'm actually developing a tool that hooks into a bunch of other interpreters and engines to allow others to write tools for it. Unfortunately hosting is not an option for my application. I'll be checking the path variable then, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What Nicol said. You will be better served by scanning PATH against the list of known executables (but even that is not a guarantee as many of my local installs are not in PATH). Still, I think there is a better chance of finding those scripting engines that don't leave their traces in the registry. Or maybe use a combination of mechanisms.